# $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and the set of oriented geodesics

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic, projection-matrices

[image]
How can $G/D$ be identified with the set of (oriented) geodesics?

Comment: This is the orbit-stabilizer theorem: if a group $G$ acts transitively on $\Omega$ with stabilizer $H={\rm Stab}(\omega)$, then $\Omega\cong G/H$ are equivalent as $G$-sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ acts transitively on the oriented  geodesics and the subgroup fixing the oriented imaginary axis (ie. fixing both $i\infty$ and $0$) is $D$.

The oritended geodesic represented by $gD$ is $gD0\to gDi\infty$.